# How to avoid stringing?

Tags: fdm, calibration, print-material

How can I avoid the irregularities and stringing in the print.
Printer Used: Fortus 450mc

Model: PC

Model tip: T10

Support tip: T12SR

Support: SR-100

Slice Height: 0.0050 in

I have printed two objects using Grabcad print (with Insight)
1) Voronoi bear:
The voronoi bear has missing layers/unattached layer at its bottom everything else seems OK. I do notice  a bit of stringing though.
[image: Top view of voronoi bear]
[image: Side view]
[image: Missing/uattached layers]
2) Cylinder with hollow channels:
The cylinder has a lot of visible stringing and one of the channels is slightly deformed. 
[image: Top View]
[image: Front View]
[image: stringing]
Please refer to the attached images.

Please let me know if any additional details are needed.

Comment: Nice post, description and photos. However, what is the question? Could you edit your post and explicitly state a question?

Comment: Can you add print settings, and also list what calibration steps you have performed.

Comment: You'll need to fine tune your retraction settings to eliminate (or at least minimize) stringing. What slicer are you using?

Comment: Did I miss something, or was the filament material never mentioned?  This is a whole different issue with some materials, such as PETG.

Answer (score 4):

I've been able to reduce stringing by reducing the nozzle temp in 2°C increments until it goes away.
You'll also want to increase your retraction settings a bit.

The problem is caused by the plastic being too hot and oozing out of the nozzle - it's a bit too runny.

Search Thingiverse for Heat Towers.  You'll need to edit the G-code so that your printer adjusts the nozzle temp at each layer.  That will give you a really good indication of the best temperature for the given material.

Keep in mind you'll want to print it for each new brand (and sometimes color) of filament.

Comment: Good note about different colors from the same manufacturer sometimes having different ideal temperatures. I find that rainbow colors are pretty uniform, but black, white, and silver can vary greatly.